# Changing color of all headers in pdf output by RMarkdown

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown

I want to change the colour of all the headers in the pdf document created by Rmarkdown. The headers are not properly visible in the black. I am changing the fonts and sizes by this code in latex.

```
---
title: "PBMC proliferation assay"
author: "Koundinya Desiraju"
output:
  pdf_document:
    highlight: tango
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
---


\fontsize{14}{20}
\selectfont
```

Is there a way i can do this with a script like this? My knowledge of latex is zero. so,please help me. Basically I want all headings specified by # or ## in RMarkdown to be in different color in pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Jon. I am posting the answer for completion sake. The code you mentioned in mystyles.sty file changes only the size and font of the headers. But if I have to change the color, keeping the RMarkdown document same, the content of mystyles.sty are as follows.

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
{\color{red}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{red}\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{red}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{red}\thesubsection}{1em}{}
```

The links you posted are very helpful Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. I used latex quite a lot and rmarkdown keeps giving me these kinds of headaches once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

The headers go to the .tex file as \section and \subsection. I think  the easiest way to solve this issue is combining this two posts:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown

Explains how to add a preamble to the tex document using a .sty file in the same folder.

And this post:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti

Which explains how to use the titlesec package in latex.

Your rmd would be something like this:

```
---
title: "PBMC proliferation assay"
author: "Koundinya Desiraju"
output:
  pdf_document:
    includes:
      in_header: mystyles.sty
    highlight: tango
    keep_tex: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
---

# HEADER 1
## HEADER 2
```

And you should create a file called mystyles.sty which would be similar to:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
```